# How do I vibrate Android Phone from Java program in Laptop?

Tags: android, vibration

My requirement is that I have a java program on running on my laptop and I want to send vibrate or any kind of sound alert to my Android mobile.

The mobile will be connected on Bluetooth. How do I achieve this?

Comment: hope it help: http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-simple-spp.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.